VCRUNTIME140.dll error on launching Blender
A system error occurs when I attempt to launch Blender, and this has suddenly happened since yesterday.
I am running on the latest update of Windows.

The code execution cannot proceed because VCRUNTIME140.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.

I attempted reinstalling the program from the official site and MS Store, and also attempted to run the repair program, but that also failed with the following error message;

The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with the package. The error code is 2753."
"blender setup was interrupted. Your system has not been modified. To install this program at a later time, please run the installation again.

The only addon I use is BlenderKit, which I installed recently and I doubt that it had anything to do with this.
A similar question was asked on Blender Projects but was not fully answered: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/107741
Any tips would be appreciated.


If you Google search for the missing DLL you will quickly find it is part of Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable  which can be downloaded from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

The problem has been solved, thank you very much.

Hi. Please don't add "Solved" to your question or title. Instead we encourage you to post an answer below with a short description of the solution and what steps you took to reach it. Perhaps add a few images illustrating the workflow and final results. See How do I write a good answer?

Thank you for the help and clarification.
The solution I found to work was to install the updated Visual C++ from:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

I restarted the computer and launched blender, and it opened as normal.
